# Combine - how to proceed to decode a local json file if online fetch failed?

Tags: swift, combine

I have an up-to-date json file hosted online and a local json file in my Xcode workspace. I would like to proceeed to decode a locally stored file if fetching failed: `MyError.fetchError` e.g. for no internet connection. This is the pipeline:

```
func fetchAndDecode<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<T, MyError> {
    fetchURL(url: url)
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .mapError { error in
            if let error = error as? DecodingError {
                return MyError.parsingError
            }  else {
                return MyError.fetchError //here somehow proceed to parse local json file
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.mapError` is the wrong operator because it considers only the `Error` branch.

`fetchURL` returns obviously `Data`, so before decoding the data you have to replace the fetch error with the local data.

Before the `.decode...` line insert

```
.replaceError(with: try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "local", withExtension: "json")!))
```

and delete the `.mapError` operator.

`local.json` represents the file name of the local file in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose an alternate but similar method to download the data and handle the error, using the `async` functions introduced for iOS 15.

Create a function that reads the data asynchronously and returns the data from the server if the connection worked, otherwise it will return the local JSON if a problem was found:

```
func getData(fromURL url: URL) async -> Data {

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                  print("HTTP response: \(response.debugDescription)")

              // Found an issue: return the local JSON
              return localJSON
              }

        // If everything is OK, return the data from the server
        return data
}
```

Decode the data returned:

```
// Use the code below in an asynchronous environment -
// either an async function or inside a Task { } closure

        let data = await getData(fromURL: url)
        do {
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            print("Decoded JSON: \(decoded)")
            return decoded
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding JSON: \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```